# Why are fibroblast used so commonly in cell biology?

Tags: cell-biology

Fibroblasts are some of the most commonly used cells in cell biology. What are the properties of those cells which makes them commonly used ?

Comment: I'd guess its because the cells are pretty easy to get and they can be preserved and used over time.

Comment: agree with @shigeta. Also, they can be differentiated.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Why can they be easily differentiated?

Comment: This is more a matter of the cells being cooperative and someone getting lucky and finding a protocol to do so.  There could be and probably are cells that differentiate more easily and are easier to maintain, but we haven't really found them yet.  Now we're getting into a real answer - @WYSIWYG do you want to start putting this in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments by Shigeta and WYSIWYG :-

1.They are easy to get and they can be preserved and used over time.

2.They can be differentiated easily.

3.Due to historic reasons - someone getting lucky and finding a protocol for these cells.